# Android reorder items list concept

Tags: android

I have to implement some list of items that have to be reordered.

My first thought was drag&drop behaviour - user long clicks on some item and drag it lower or upper to change its position. But there is a problem - drag&drop had been implemented since Android 3.x

Do you have any other user friendly ideas to design this kind of reorder list ?
What way did you implement it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try implementing a sort order which user will select from a context menu

Comment: User has to sort it manually - there will be no pattern to sorting items.

Answer (score 0):

if my list isnt to long i change my adapter with help of compareTo of Collections

Comment: My question is mainly about user interface - I am looking for some alternative to drag&dropping items.